# Merged cells - borders not matching up

Tags: tables

I've got a little problem concerning merged cells in latex. This is the code I used for my table:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor,colortbl}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
 & \multicolumn{4}{l}{August '13} & \multicolumn{4}{|l}{September '13} & \multicolumn{4}{|l}{Oktober '13} & \multicolumn{4}{|l}{November '13} & \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Dezember '13} \\
\hline
Kalenderwoche&32&33&34&35&36&37&38&39&40&41&42&43&44&45&46&47&48&49&50&51\\
\hline
Abgabe Probekapitel&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&&\\
\end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

And this is my output:
(sorry - I cannot post images)

```
|________________|________________|
|___|____|____|___|___|____|____|___|
```

As you can see, the vertical lines do not exactly match up. How can I solve this problem? Do you know any better methods to create tables?

Thanks for your help in advance!
Jurg, Switzerland

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Comment: Use `|` judiciously. Instead of `\multicolumn{4}{|l}`, if use use `\multicolumn{4}{l|}` at appropriate places, you get every thing correct.

Comment: Rules belong to the column before them (except the first rule that belongs to the first column).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Remarks

I wasn't able to reproduce your problem, but with the following implementation it works fine for me. I cleaned the code a little and removed all unnecessary packages.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \begin{tabular}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
        \hline
        &
        \multicolumn{4}{l}{August '13} &
        \multicolumn{4}{|l}{September '13} &
        \multicolumn{4}{|l}{Oktober '13} &
        \multicolumn{4}{|l}{November '13} &
        \multicolumn{4}{|l|}{Dezember '13} \\
        \hline
        Kalenderwoche &
        32 & 33 & 34 & 35 &
        36 & 37 & 38 & 39 &
        40 & 41 & 42 & 43 &
        44 & 45 & 46 & 47 &
        48 & 49 & 50 & 51 \\
        \hline
        Abgabe Probekapitel &
        & & & & &
        & & & & &
        & & & & &
        & & & & \\
    \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: That looks great! Thank you very much. Now I get the correct output just like the one you posted. Thanks again - you were a great help & you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @Jurg Thank you for commenting! This is what makes the TeX.SX Community a great place.